# Discord js copying another bot's embed's attached image and description to another channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to copy another bot's embed file to another channel. Is there a way to it? I've seen other codes but it doesn't seem to work on mine. If anyone can give a simple way (well, any way) to code it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code to your question to help readers understand what's going on and give you some solutions? If there are any errors make sure to post these too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have access to the `message` object:

```js
console.log(message.embeds[0]) // this is how you can get the embed
```

From there you can access [all its properties](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed). In your case, `.image` and `.description`

---

To send a message to a specified channel:

```js
const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('<Channel ID>');

channel.send('Whatever message you want to send');
```

Comment: apologies for the noob question addition but, it seems to send the entire embed. I tried just grabbing image and description but it still sends the entire embed